# Why can't I derive Lindblad equation in this way(by Taylor expand)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-optics

Assume a system with a Hamiltonian

\begin{aligned}
H & =H_s+H_b+H_{sb}\\
&=\hbar\omega_0 a^{\dagger}a+\hbar\omega\alpha^{\dagger}\alpha+\hbar(\kappa\alpha^{\dagger}a+\kappa^*\alpha a^{\dagger})
\end{aligned}
And we can describe the motion of density matrix of system by
\begin{aligned}
\rho_s(t+dt)&=tr_b\{e^{-iHdt/\hbar}\rho_s(t)\otimes|0\rangle\langle0|e^{iHdt/\hbar}\}\\
&=\sum_{k}\langle k|e^{-iHdt/\hbar}\rho_s(t)\otimes|0\rangle\langle0|e^{iHdt/\hbar}|k\rangle
\end{aligned}
In the Karus representation, we can introduce 
$$
M_k(dt)=\langle k|e^{-iHdt/\hbar}|0\rangle
$$
then we can rewrite 
$$
\rho_s(t+dt)=\sum_k M_k(dt)\rho_s(t) M_k^{\dagger}(dt)
$$
We can calculate $M_k$
\begin{aligned}
M_0(dt) &= e^{-iH_s dt/\hbar}\langle 0|(1+(-iH_{sb}dt/\hbar)+(-iH_{sb}dt/\hbar)^2/2)+o(dt^2)|0\rangle\\
&=e^{-iH_s dt/\hbar}\langle 0|(-\hbar^2|k|^2a^{\dagger}a/2)|0\rangle\\
&=e^{-iH_s dt/\hbar}(-\hbar^2dt^2|k|^2a^{\dagger}a/2)
\end{aligned}
In a same way, we can get
$$
M_1(dt) = e^{-iH_s dt/\hbar}(-i\hbar dt^2\kappa a)
$$
and for $k>=2$
$$
M_k(dt) = o(dt^2)
$$
then, we get the equation
\begin{aligned}
\rho_s(t+dt)&=\rho_s(t)-(idt/\hbar)[H_s,\rho_s(t)]-dt^2(\hbar^2|\kappa|^2/2)(a^{\dagger}a\rho_s(t)\\
&+\rho_s(t)a^{\dagger}a+2a\rho_s(t)a^{\dagger})+o(dt^2)
\end{aligned}
We find the $\mathcal{L}(\rho)$ is ~$dt^2$, but in the Lindblad equation, this term should be ~ $dt$.

I can't find where is wrong. But it's really different from Lindblad equation.

Comment: Furthermore, $dt_{}^{2}$ term doesn't look like "Trace Preserving".

Comment: I am not sure if this is the main problem, but your calculation of $M_k$ seems incorrect, since $e^H \neq e^{H_s} e^{H_b} e^{H_{sb}}$

Comment: $e^H \neq e^{H_s} e^{H_b+H_{sb}}$ will not change the result.This introduce a correction $e^{[H_s,H_b+H_{sb}]/2}$~ $dt^2$ and if  we expand it in $M_1$ and $M_0$, will find this  correction term will result in 0.